# MySQL: Можно ли сменить порядок выводу данных, относительно колонки по которой идет поиск

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, order-by

Смысл в чём, припустим у нас есть таблица **article**:

```
|id|title|description|
|1 |А 1  |B 3        |
|2 |А 2  |B 2        |
|3 |А 3  |B 1        |
|4 |B 1  |А 3        |
|5 |B 2  |А 2        |
|6 |B 3  |А 1        |
```

При выборе `SELECT id FROM article WHERE (title LIKE "%B%" OR description LIKE "%B%")` Сначала должны идти к примеру id title а потом уже description і тут момент не банальная сортировка по id а именно по заданной колонке, то есть порядок отображения ид неважен, но главное чтобы сначала были те записи в которых совпали в title а потому уже в description или наоборот.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
ORDER BY (title LIKE "%B%") DESC
```

Выражение вернёт `1`, если значение соответствует шаблону, и `0`, если не соответствует.

`DESC` задаёт сортировку по уменьшению - т.е. сначала будут записи, где значение соответствует шаблону.